# Scala read continuous http stream

Tags: python, scala, bottle, http-streaming, akka-stream

How can I connect to and read a continuous (chunked) http stream in scala? For example, if I have this simple service written in python/bottle:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()

import gevent
from bottle import route, run

@route('/stream')
def stream():
    while True:
        yield 'blah\n'
        gevent.sleep(1)

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8100, server='gevent')
```

I'm planning to use `akka-stream` to process the data, I just need a way to retrieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Basically, you do a single request to an uri that produces a chunked response. The response entity contains a dataBytes stream. In case of a chunked response, this will be the stream of chunks. In case of a non-chunked response (HttpEntity.Strict), this will be a stream with just a single chunk.

Obviously you can also explicitly match on the entity to see if it is HttpEntity.Chunked, but usually you want to retain the ability to handle non-chunked responses as well.

In a real world application you would not use runForeach to execute a side effect, but do some processing with the dataBytes stream.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{Uri, HttpRequest}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object ChunkTestClient extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("test")
  import system.dispatcher

  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  val source = Uri("https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/ChunkedScript")
  val finished = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = source)).flatMap { response =>
    response.entity.dataBytes.runForeach { chunk =>
      println(chunk.utf8String)
    }
  }
}
```