# Scala read large set of chunk data through akka streaming

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to read large chunk of data through scala as explained here : [Scala read continuous http stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106851/scala-read-continuous-http-stream)

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{Uri, HttpRequest}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object ChunkTestClient extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("test")
  import system.dispatcher

  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  val source = Uri("https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/ChunkedScript")
  val finished = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = source)).flatMap { response =>
    response.entity.dataBytes.runForeach { chunk =>
      println(chunk.utf8String)
    }
  }
}
```

The above code snippet works fine for most of case. But in case the response data is huge, or source is continuously streaming large set of data, then chunk response does not work, neither it throw any error, it just kills silently. This seems to be case of back-pressure where rate of data production is grater than rate of consumption.  Is there any way to handle large size\streaming  of data with akka http streaming. What can be done in above code to handle back pressure at client side.

Comment: I think your assumption that back-pressure is causing the problem is incorrect. There might be an error which is silently ignored and causing the stream to stop (default behaviour). I'd suggest add error logging https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#logging-errors and supervision decider https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#supervision-strategies

Comment: Does it work if you add `Await.ready(finished, Duration.Inf)` at the very end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to work this withoutSizeLimit(). I also tried withSizeLimit() but that does not worked for me.

`

```
object ChunkTestClient extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("test")
  import system.dispatcher

  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  val source = Uri("https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/ChunkedScript")
  val finished = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = source)).flatMap { response =>
    response.entity.withoutSizeLimit().dataBytes.runForeach { chunk =>
      println(chunk.utf8String)
    }
  }
}
```

`